# Is it always possible to swap columns of a matrix by a left hand side multiplication?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I was thinking about swapping the columns of the matrix. It is well known that if you want to swap 2 columns of a matrix, you do a right hand side multiplication with a permutation matrix $T_{ij}$, where $i$ and $j$ are the rows you wish to swap.

In the following example I want to swap column 1 and 2, so I multiply the matrix whose columns I wish to swap with $T_{12}$ from the right.

$$
    \begin{pmatrix}
    1 & x & x^2 \\
    1 & y & y^2 \\
    1 & z & z^2 \\
    \end{pmatrix}.
    \begin{pmatrix}
    0 & 1 & 0 \\
    1 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 1 \\
    \end{pmatrix}=
    \begin{pmatrix}
    x & 1 & x^2 \\
    y & 1 & y^2 \\
    z & 1 & z^2 \\
    \end{pmatrix}
$$

My question is this: does there always exist a matrix $A$ such that:

$$A.    \begin{pmatrix}
    1 & x & x^2 \\
    1 & y & y^2 \\
    1 & z & z^2 \\
    \end{pmatrix}=    \begin{pmatrix}
    x & 1 & x^2 \\
    y & 1 & y^2 \\
    z & 1 & z^2 \\
    \end{pmatrix}$$

If so, what properties should I expect it to have? If it doesn't in all cases, why? Are there any theorems relating to this?

EDIT: I used the entries $1,x,x^2$ in the matrix, but I'm not asking about square matrices taking such forms. I actually want to ask if this is true for any arbitrary entries in the matrix I wish to swap columns of. What I've tried are thinking about the multiplying the inverse of $T_{ij}$ to both sides, but that won't work.

Comment: What have you tried?  For instance, have you tried replacing $A$ with $\begin{pmatrix}a_{11} & a_{12} & a_{13} \\ a_{21} & a_{22} & a_{23} \\ a_{31} & a_{32} & a_{33} \end{pmatrix}$, multiplying it out and seeing if any set of choices for the $a_{ij}$ can produce the result you want?

Comment: Edited my question. I don't think solving simultaneous equations is the way to go about showing this. Also I hoping to find an answer for a general $m*m$ matrix, so I hope for a more abstract proof.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since left-multiplication forms linear combinations of the rows of a matrix (as rows of the result), we have an obstruction when the rows do not span the space of all possible row vectors. It is notably impossible to swap a column that is zero with one that is not (as this breaks out of the subspace where the corresponding entry of any row is zero).

On the other hand, for the subset of square matrices whose rows span the whole space, i.e., the invertible matrices, one can obtain any matrix of the same size by an appropriate left multiplication (proof left as exercise). In particular we may simulate for a specific such matrix any column operation by a left-multiplication, though of course what this really does is a row operation.